# GROUP BY clause order omitting results in Oracle 11g query

Tags: sql, oracle11g, group-by

I have a simple query that appears to give the desired result:

```
select op.opr, op.last, op.dept, count(*) as counter 
from DWRVWR.BCA_M_OPRIDS1 op
where op.opr = '21B'
group by op.opr, op.last ,op.dept;
```

My original query returns no results.  The only difference was the order of the group by clause:

```
select op.opr, op.last, op.dept, count(*) as counter 
from DWRVWR.BCA_M_OPRIDS1 op
where op.opr = '21B'
group by op.opr, op.dept, op.last;
```

In actuality, this was part of a much larger, more complicated query, but I narrowed down the problem to this.  All documentation I was able to find states that the order of the group by clause doesn't matter.  I really want to understand why I am getting different results, as I would have to review all of my queries that use the group by clause, if there is a potential issue.  I'm using SQL Developer, if it matters.

Also, if the order of the group by clause did not matter and every field not used in an aggregate function is required to be listed in the group by clause, wouldn't the group by clause simply be redundant and seemingly unnecessary?

Comment: I actually ran into this problem yesterday, but in SQL Server. My issue was that the date I was trying to order, and group by was not the information that I was searching for. Maybe it has to do with the physical data itself and not the ORDER or GROUP BY clauses.

Comment: Sounds like a bug. And vaguely familiar but not sure where from. Which patch level are you on? And is it a simple table or a view? The execution plans for both queries might be interesting too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> All documentation I was able to find states that the order of the group by clause doesn't matter

That's not entirely true, it depends.

The grouping functionality is not impacted by the order of columns in the `GROUP BY` clause. It will produce the same group set regardless of the order. Perhaps that's what those documentation that you found were referring to. However the order does matter for other aspects.

Before Oracle 10g, the `GROUP BY` performed implicitly an `ORDER BY`, so the order of the columns in the `GROUP BY` clause did matter. The group sets are the same, but only ordered differently. Starting with Oracle10g, if you want the result set to be in any specific order, then you must add an `ORDER BY` clause. Other databases have similar history.

Another case where the order matters is if you have indexes on the table. Multi-column indexes are only used if the columns exactly match the columns specified in the `GROUP BY` or `ORDER BY` clauses. So if you change the order, your query will not use the index and will perform differently. The result is the same, but the performance is not.

Also the order of the columns in the `GROUP BY` clause becomes important if you use some features like `ROLLUP`. This time the results themselves will not be the same.

It is recommended to follow the best practice of listing the fields in the `GROUP BY` clause in the order of the hierarchy. This makes the query more readable and more easily maintainable.

> Also, if the order of the group by clause did not matter and every field not used in an aggregate function is required to be listed in the group by clause, wouldn't the group by clause simply be redundant and seemingly unnecessary?

No, the `GROUP BY` clause is mandatory in the standard SQL and in Oracle. There is only one exception in which you can omit the `GROUP BY` clause, if you want the aggregate functions to apply to the entire result set. In this case, your `SELECT` list must consist only of aggregate expressions.

Comment: Hi Racil.   I was referring to the documentation you specified.  That documentation states, "It will produce the same group set regardless of the order. " but my question is specifically regarding why it did not produce the same group set.  I was aware of the ROLLUP and CUBE exceptions.  I hadn't thought of the index portion, but this is a view with no indexes and, in any, event, it should not have changed the results.

Comment: The indexes are defined on the table, but a view can use them like any query does. Yes, that shouldn't change the result in a sense that the same records are returned. However, you said that this *"was part of a much larger, more complicated query"*, so if the sorting is changed when you changed the order of the columns in the `GROUP BY` clause, and that order impacted the rest of the larger query, then you may end up with different results. Nobody can answer that part of your question without looking at the entire query and possibly the environment.

Comment: What I meant was that originally the query was much larger, but I found the problem by paring it down.  I see the problem with the two queries as posted.  I have checked an see no indexes on the view.  Are you saying that even though I cannot see the index that the optimizer would realize the original table was indexed and use it?  How would it possibly know there was a multi-column index? Does it just assume an index if those columns are sorted?

Comment: So you're saying that if you run those two queries alone exactly as you posted them in the question, they return different results? Run them directly as queries, not in a view. If they still return different results, check and compare their execution plans. The execution plan tells you what indexes are used, if any.

Comment: Yes, that is exactly what I was trying to say.  Unfortunately, it would appear that I probably hit a dead end here however, since I do not have access to the tables themselves, not do I have the necessary priveleges to do an explain plan.  I am only an end user to the views (business analyst), not a DBA or a developer.  I assume I cannot do the explain plan because I have read only rights.  I thank you for your time and effort, though, and will mark your answer complete, since I cannot provide you with the details you need to provide the full answer.